# Windowsで現在ログイン中のユーザーにパスワードが設定されているか取得する方法ありますか？

Tags: c#, windows, vba

スクリプトや、API,WMIなど、言語や手段は問いません。

Windowsで現在ログインしているユーザーにパスワードが設定されているかどうかの情報を取得できる方法を教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [stackoverflow.comにある同様の質問](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6556594/4366193)でも、ここで既に回答されたような「空のパスワードでログインしてみる」方法のようです。

Comment: 言語は問わないとありますが、`c#` `vba` タグが付いているのは一例としてですか？

Comment: 解決した場合には、ぜひその内容でご自身で解答を投稿し、48時間後にチェックを付けていただけるとコミュニティの為になりますし、Tokyo12さんにも評価点が付きます。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 解決！

C++ですが、下記のような感じで取得出来ました。ありがとうございました。(__)

```
wstring user = "HogeHoge";

HANDLE h;
CEdit* edit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
CString s;
s.AppendFormat(L"ユーザー: %s\r\n", user.c_str());
int res = LogonUser(user.c_str(), L".", L"", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &h);
if (res == 0) {
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    s.AppendFormat(L"Error: %d\r\n", error);
    if (error == ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION) {
        s.AppendFormat(L"このユーザーにはパスワードが設定されていません");
    }
    else if (error == ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE){
        s.AppendFormat(L"このユーザーにはパスワードが設定されています");
    }
    else {
        s.AppendFormat(L"不明なエラー");
    }
    edit->SetWindowTextW(s);
}
else {
    s.AppendFormat(L"Result: %d", res);
    edit->SetWindowTextW(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(2015/02/27 20:44追記)下記回答は使えないようです。

---

ローカルドメインのユーザーであれば、Windowsのコマンド`net`を利用して

```
net user %USERNAME%
```

とすると、パスワードの有無を含む様々な情報が取得できます。

Comment: 多分そのコマンドで表示される[パスワードあり]って項目のことだと思いますが、確かそれってパスワードを再設定するときにパスワードなしでも良いかの設定であって、今現在のパスワードの設定/未設定では無かったと思います。
参考：https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/a37055f2-103b-4671-95fb-de3b3b23902b/net-user-?forum=w7itprogeneralja

Comment: パスワードを設定していても、"パスワードを無制限にする"にチェックが入っていると"パスワードあり：No"になりますから使えないでしょうね。

しかし質問主さんはなぜパスワードの設定有無を調べたいのだろうか？
背景がわからなければ回答しにくいような。

Comment: @BladeanMericle and LainZero ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答に使えない旨を追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

酷い方法ですがSystem.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dllを参照して

```
bool HasPassword()
{
    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        try
        {
            return !pc.ValidateCredentials(Environment.UserName, "");
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

のようにログインしてみれば分かるかと。`ValidateCredentials`は`False`または例外を返します。

Comment: ログインを試してみる方法でうまくいきました！！！ありがとうございます！